# for let of loop doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, let

When I use for in loop, it works, and for of loop just doesn't get anything :(
Here is my code

```
'use strict'

var match_table = [
  {'project': 'Laveral', 'template': 'Blade'},
  {'project': 'Ember.js', 'template': 'Handlebars'},
  {'project': 'Meteor', 'template': 'Handlebars'},
];

// count project number by template
var templateMap = new Array();
match_table.forEach(function(listItem){
  var template = listItem['template'];
  if (!templateMap[template]) {
    templateMap[template] = new Object();
  }
  templateMap[template]['name'] = template;
  if (templateMap[template]['count']) {
    templateMap[template]['count']++;
  } else {
    templateMap[template]['count'] = 1;
  }
});

//console.log(templateMap);

// for loop fails
for (let value of templateMap) {
  console.log(value);
}

templateMap.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
})
```

also forEach doesn't output anything either~?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for-of` cannot iterate through objects (since they are not iterable as per the standard).

So you either must use the good old `for-in`

OR

Use the non-standardised yet [`Object.entries()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries):

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

`templateMap` in your case is an object, not an array, since you assign string keys into it (and JS arrays indexes are numeric within `[0; 2^32-1)` range).

Comment: I was interested how big the overhead of `Object.entries()` was: http://jsperf.com/object-entries-4711. It's far from neglectable. It's a rehash of `iteritems()` vs `item()` in Python.

Comment: @Kay it allocates heaps of arrays, but interesting, thanks.

Comment: @Kay You should add at least hasOwnProperty check.

Comment: @Ginden, I don't think that is needed anymore since IE9. Nevertheless: http://jsperf.com/object-entries-4711/2.

Comment: zerkms: JS arrays are limited to 2^32 AFAIR, with larger lengths being truncated.

Comment: @Ginden thanks, indeed I confused terms: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type

Answer (score 1):

Is `template` numeric?  It looks like you're about to misuse an Array as an Object.  Try `templateMap.push(new Object())` to append to the array instead.